# using maven in linux

Tags: linux, maven

I'm using Maven3 in Linux (CentOs 5.x)

And run linux) **mvn install -Preal**

But following error occurs.

---

**Here's error messages**

```
...
[ERROR] /data/byto_openapi/src/main/java/com/byto/openapi/home/HomeServiceImpl.java:[36,51] package org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /data/byto_openapi/src/main/java/com/byto/openapi/home/HomeServiceImpl.java:[37,51] package org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /data/byto_openapi/src/main/java/com/byto/openapi/home/HomeServiceImpl.java:[38,37] package org.springframework.orm.ibatis does not exist
[ERROR] /data/byto_openapi/src/main/java/com/byto/openapi/home/HomeServiceImpl.java:[39,48] package org.springframework.security.core.context does not exist
[ERROR] /data/byto_openapi/src/main/java/com/byto/openapi/home/HomeServiceImpl.java:[40,52] package org.springframework.security.core.userdetails does not exist
[ERROR] /data/byto_openapi/src/main/java/com/byto/openapi/home/HomeServiceImpl.java:[41,37] package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist
[ERROR] /data/byto_openapi/src/main/java/com/byto/openapi/home/HomeServiceImpl.java:[42,49] package org.springframework.transaction.annotation does not exist
[ERROR] /data/byto_openapi/src/main/java/com/byto/openapi/home/HomeServiceImpl.java:[43,40] package org.springframework.web.multipart does not exist
[ERROR] /data/byto_openapi/src/main/java/com/byto/openapi/home/HomeServiceImpl.java:[44,40] package org.springframework.web.multipart does not exist
[ERROR] /data/byto_openapi/src/main/java/com/byto/openapi/home/HomeServiceImpl.java:[56,24] package com.sun.mail.smtp does not exist
[ERROR] /data/byto_openapi/src/main/java/com/byto/openapi/home/HomeServiceImpl.java:[58,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Service
[ERROR] @Service
[ERROR] /data/byto_openapi/src/main/java/com/byto/openapi/home/HomeServiceImpl.java:[59,1] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Transactional
[ERROR] @Transactional
[ERROR] /data/byto_openapi/src/main/java/com/byto/openapi/home/HomeServiceImpl.java:[64,9] cannot find symbol
...
```

---

**And this is CLASSPATH**

```
declare -x CLASSPATH=".:/usr/java/jdk/lib/tools.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/lib:/usr/local/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-146.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-ext-jdk16-146.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/javapns-jdk16-161.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjweaver-1.6.8.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/cglib-2.2.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-template-2.2.2.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-digester-2.0.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-ext-jdk16-146.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.1.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-config-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ibatis-sqlmap-2.3.4.726.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-ldap-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-pool-1.3.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-api-2.2.2.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/mail.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/aspectjrt-1.6.9.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-test-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.2.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/derbyclient-10.4.2.0.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-acl-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/javapns-jdk16-161.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/asm-3.1.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.2.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.10.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-1.3.2.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/activation.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.19-bin.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-ldap-core-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/cos.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-jsp-2.2.2.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/org.springframework.roo.annotations-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/tiles-core-2.2.2.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/junit-4.7.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-taglibs-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-146.jar:/data/byto_openapi/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/javax.inject-1.jar"
```

As you can see all the JARs are included in CLASSPATH..

---

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>cyoz</groupId>
<artifactId>cyoz</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <database.defaultAutoCommit>true</database.defaultAutoCommit>
    <database.validationQuery>select 1</database.validationQuery>
    <database.testWhileIdle>true</database.testWhileIdle>
    <database.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis>7200000</database.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis>

    <spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <tiles.version>2.2.2</tiles.version>
    <image.path>/data/api_svn_www/file/image</image.path>
</properties>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
            <targetPath>${basedir}/target/webapp</targetPath>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${basedir}/target/classes</targetPath>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <filters>
        <filter>${basedir}/src/main/resources/spring-common-bean-context.xml</filter>
        <filter>${basedir}/src/main/resources/byto.cyoz.properties</filter>
    </filters>

</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <database.classname>me.kun.log4jdbc.DriverSpy</database.classname>
            <database1.url>jdbc:log4jdbc:mysql://211.174.62.34:3306/bytoapi?autoReconnect=true</database1.url>
            <database1.username>bytoapi</database1.username>
            <database1.password>bytoapi1213</database1.password>
            <database2.url>jdbc:log4jdbc:mysql://211.174.62.34:3306/byto_memo?autoReconnect=true</database2.url>
            <database2.username>byto_memo</database2.username>
            <database2.password>memo1213</database2.password>
        </properties> 
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation> 

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp/</warSourceDirectory>
                        <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalProjectnatures>
                            <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                        </additionalProjectnatures>
                        <additionalBuildcommands>
                            <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                        </additionalBuildcommands>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                        <wtpversion>1.5</wtpversion>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                        <dependenciesAsLibraries>true</dependenciesAsLibraries>
                        <useFullNames>false</useFullNames>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.5</source>
                        <target>1.5</target>
                        <!--<encoding>EUC-KR</encoding> -->
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-rebel-xml</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <inherited>false</inherited>
                            <configuration>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>http://211.174.62.34:8080/manager/html</url>
                        <path>/cyoz</path>
                        <username>tomcat</username>
                        <password>tomcat</password>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>real</id>
        <properties>
            <database.classname>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</database.classname>
            <database1.url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/bytoapi?autoReconnect=true</database1.url>
            <database1.username>bytoapi</database1.username>
            <database1.password>bytoapi1213</database1.password>
            <database2.url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/byto_memo?autoReconnect=true</database2.url>
            <database2.username>byto_memo</database2.username>
            <database2.password>memo1213</database2.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>

</profiles>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

---

**linux /etc/profile which set CLASSPATH to compile *.java**

```sh
# tomcat CLASSPATH
SOURCE_FOLDER=/data/byto_openapi
LIBRARY_FOLDER=$SOURCE_FOLDER/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$LIBRARY_FOLDER
for file in `find $LIBRARY_FOLDER -name "*.jar" -type f`
do
    export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$file
done
```

Comment: More information needed. As is, your question does not make sense. Maven works on Linux just like it does on Windows.  What project are you trying to compile? How did you generate that class path? Can you post the pom.xml? Without any other information, it just appears that the pom.xml is missing a refence.

Comment: Why you specify dependencies manually instead of declare them in `pom.xml` and allow to maven manage all project's dependencies? Also I not sure that maven will respect `CLASSPATH` variable..

Comment: @php-coder I do respect, but I'm just editing other person's source.

Comment: @php-coder and he used linux make file to compile, but it looks bad to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven does not look for the `CLASSPATH` variable to pick up its dependencies. Instead, it manages its own dependencies as specified in the `pom.xml` file. Indeed, this is the number one reason for using Maven in my book.

Have a look at [Maven - Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) for a quick start to dependency management with Maven.

For inspecting the actual classpaths used by the Maven plugins run the build with the `--debug` argument, for instance

> mvn --debug clean install -Preal

Comment: do you mean that maven doesn't even use CLASSPATHs JARs files?

Comment: AFAIK `CLASSPATH` is completely ignored. You can run `mvn --debug install -Preal` to get the actual compile classpath.

Comment: @PatrickJeon good to know, I've updated my answer with the debugging instructions.